# Access a cloud firestore document within a cloud function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

Within my Google Firebase Firstore database I would like to gather aggregative data such as how many documents a collection has. Since Firestore does not provide aggregative queries I'm attempting to write a cloud function that will increment a field every time a document is added to the database which will contain the number of documents a collection has.

The problem I'm having is I cannot for the life of me figure out how to grab documents from Firestore within a cloud function using nodejs.

Here's what I'm doing:

At the top of my `index.js` file I configure the admin SDK and what have you like this:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
```

Then for my cloud function I do this:

```
exports.createPost = functions.firestore
  .document('posts/{post_id}')
  .onCreate(event => {

    // Get the post object
    var post = event.data.data();

    var senderID = post["sender_id"]; // This is not null

    // Access to user's document and the main ledger document
    const userDocRef = admin.database().ref('/users').orderByChild("user_id").equalTo(senderID).once('value')
    const ledgerDocRef = admin.database().ref('/posts/ledger').once('value');

    return Promise.all([userDocRef, ledgerDocRef]).then(snapshot => {

        const user = snapshot[0].val();
        const ledger = snapshot[1].val();

        console.log("user => "+user); // Logs: user => null
        console.log("ledger => "+ledger); // Logs: ledger => null

        const userPostCount = user["user_name"];
        const globalPostCount = ledger["global_post_count"] + 1;

        const userUpdate = user.update({"post_count" : userPostCount});
        const ledgerUpdate = ledger.update({"global_post_count" : globalPostCount});

        return Promise.all([userUpdate, ledgerUpdate]);
    });
});
```

I end up with the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'global_post_count' of null
>       at Promise.all.then.snapshot

Which I figure means something is wrong with my query but I don't know what. Both the `users` and `posts` are root level collections.

Im also getting a warning that says:

> Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and
>   quotas are severely limited.

From what I've read online, I don't think that effects it but I thought it was worth noting.

Please help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Looks like you've written a Firestore trigger, but are then reaching into Realtime Database for queries:

```
const userDocRef = admin.database().ref('/users').orderByChild("user_id").equalTo(senderID).once('value')
const ledgerDocRef = admin.database().ref('/posts/ledger').once('value');
```

If your RTDB is empty, these queries will also end up empty.

To query Firestore, you need to be using `admin.firestore()` instead of `admin.database()`.  Firestore has a [mostly different API](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.8.x/) (via the Cloud SDK I just linked) than RTDB, but they are similar in some ways.

Comment: Ohhhh I see now thats pretty slick. Thanks for answering, I've been hitting my head against the wall for the last couple hours on this one.

Comment: @DougStevenson - I'm having a similar issue and attempted your solution above within my Cloud Function `functions.https.onCall()` type call using `admin.firestore().ref('qa/content/feeds/main/content/'+contentTitle).get().then(function(doc) {...}` but am getting the error `Unhandled error TypeError: admin.firestore(...).ref is not a function`

Comment: @AdamHurwitz, you may need to import the `firebase-admin` sdk. Try adding the following lines before your code if you're still experiencing this problem:

`const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();`